# PHP file_exists stopped working this morning?

Tags: php, if-statement, file-exists

Just wondered, I have the following code:

```
            <a href="<?=$row->aw_deep_link?>">
                <?php if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'images/products/' . $row->strId . '.jpg')):?>

                <img alt="<?=$row->my_brand . ' ' . $row->line . ' ' . $row->my_product . ' - ' . $row->size.$row->unit?>" height="170" itemprop="image" src="<?=base_url() . 'images/products/' . $row->strId?>.jpg" width="170">
                <?php else:?>

                <img alt="<?=$row->my_brand . ' ' . $row->line . ' ' . $row->my_product . ' - ' . $row->size.$row->unit?>" height="170" itemprop="image" src="<?=$row->aw_image_url?>" width="170">
                <?php endif;?>

            </a>
```

Up until last night, this was performing perfectly; this morning - it's stopped, out of the blue and automatically defaults to the

> else

clause.

Has something changed with PHP?

Comment: nothing changed with PHP check if something got changed to your server and folder permissions.

Comment: As @AbhikChakraborty says check the server. PHP does not change unless you specifically choose to upgrade/downgrade it. Though in some hosting environments predominately shared hosting, this is not something controlled by you. So the host may have updated their servers PHP version. Ensure the file does exist also. But the function has not been deprecated so even if the PHP version was upgraded, this would not cause your issue.

Comment: Would this happen if the folder containing the files to check if existing had reached a certain size? @AbhikChakraborty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no files or scripts were changed that you know of (including if the image file is still actually there) then it could have been a server change / update which has caused an error.

My suggestion would be to run some simple tests in a separate file I.e. check the value of your `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable, check for the existence of the directory containing your image, then check for the existence of the image.

If you're 100% sure you have changed nothing on the server, I'd suggest contacting your host.

Answer (score 2):

You don't give enough info for anyone to give you the answer, but I would suggest checking:

1. Does $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] still equal what you expect? You could use `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` to find out.
2. Does the images/products/ directory still exist and is it readable by the user that is running this php script? Which is probably the user that Apache is running as.
3. Is `$row->strId` still valid?
4. Are there some files called `$row->strId.jpg` in the directory and are they readable by your user?

Assuming that `file_exists` is broken is the wrong place to start, check your variables that are being used to construct the file name.

Comment: +1 for this "Assuming that file_exists is broken is the wrong place to start"